# Math.round being ignored

Tags: java

```
    double energy, mass;
    double speedOfLight = 299792458.0;
    // Get mass
    System.out.print("Mass? ");
    mass = keyboard.nextDouble();
    // Calculate energy
    energy = mass*Math.pow(speedOfLight, 2);
    // Round to 1 decimal place
    energy = Math.round(energy * 10.0) / 10.0;
    System.out.printf("The energy is " +energy+ " Joules");
    // Close scanner
    keyboard.close();
```

It is returning, "The energy is 8.987551787368176E16 Joules" when it should be returning, "The energy is 89875517873681760.0 Joules"

Answer (score 4):

`Math.round` is working as intended, returning the nearest integer (but the output is in [scientific notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scientific_notation)). The problem is in the printing of the number. You can use `printf`'s [format specifiers](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Formatter.html#syntax) to print the number in the format you want:

```
System.out.printf("The energy is %.1f Joules", energy);
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, unfortunately when trying your method I am given the error message,
"Mass? 1
The energy is Exception in thread "main" java.util.IllegalFormatConversionException: d != java.lang.Double
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.failConversion(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.printInteger(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter$FormatSpecifier.print(Unknown Source)
 at java.util.Formatter.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.format(Unknown Source)
 at java.io.PrintStream.printf(Unknown Source)
 at P2.main(P2.java:42)"

Comment: Yes, I used the wrong format specifier (`d` is for long/integer, `f` is for float/double). I corrected the snippet.

Comment: Ah, thank you for that, but it still outputs, "The energy is 89875517873681760.000000 Joules" Is it possible to cut it off after the first 0?

Comment: I added a `.1` to the format specifier, which causes Java to print 1 decimal place. Similarly, you could use `.5`, if you want 5 decimal places.